# The Riemannian Curvature in Deformations

Tags: tensor-calculus, curvature, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Is there a direct correlation between the Riemannian Curvature tensor and the deformation gradient tensor in continuum mechanics?

Comment: Please note that a question that can be answered with a "yes" or "no" is not considered a good fit for this forum. You might want to expand a little (and maybe show your understanding of the question - what do you think the answer is, and why?)

Comment: Check out Ricci curvature. A gravitational field is not totally unlike the continuum mechanics situation where there's an outward stress with a spherical symmetry. [This depiction](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f7e103bf7e3affc5983cfaa856d3976c?convert_to_webp=true) gets things back to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After giving myself a crash course on the deformation gradient tensor (I hadn't heard of it before) from the "Finite Strain Theory" wikipedia page, it seems evident that these two notions are not related at all.

In summary, the Deformation Gradient Tensor is to do with the best fit *linear* approximation of a vector field around a point. In contrast, the curvature is to do with the best fit *quadratic* approximation of the same.

It seems from this article that a *large strain* can either be thought of in two ways:

1. A smooth map between *two* manifolds, being the body before and after the strain. In this conception, the Deformation Gradient Tensor is essentially the differential of this map that relates vectors in the respective tangent spaces by the [*pushforward*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)#Pushforward_of_vector_fields)
2. Thinking of the body embedded in Euclidean space, the large strain is the [*flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) of a vector field defined on a subset of the Euclidean manifold (the part that the body passes through as it deforms) - the vector field being the DGT.

In the first conception, the notion resembles a rank 2 tensor field: a linear mapping between vectors in tangent spaces. In the second conception, it is a vector field.

Neither of these is in any way related to the curvature $R$, which is a rank 4 tensor: it can be thought of as a function that operates on two vectors $X$ and $Y$ both belonging to the tangent space. $X$ and $Y$ define an infinitessimal parallelogram. $R(X,\,Y)$ spits out a *linear map* (the "curvature transformation") that tells us how a third vector $Z$ from the same tangent space is changed as it is parallel-transported around the infinitessimal loop.

The DGT involves only first spatial derivatives. The curvature (when the covariant derivative is torsion free) is a *commutator* between first order differential operators and therefore involves second order derivatives.

So the two notions are very different.

Answer (score 0):

A manifold with non-zero curvature can be seen as a deformation of a Euclidean space that involves curving. Not all deformations of a Euclidean space result in a curved manifold. Stretching, compressing and shearing do not necessarily introduce curvature. But the bending of a plane to fit a globe, that deformation, does.

Note that the bending of a plane to make a cylinder does not require deformation. In fact the Riemanian curvature of a cylinder is zero. You can see this by displacing basis vectors of a tangent space around a square inscribed on the surface. They come back unchanged.